# How is * interpreted on bash command lines?

Tags: bash, filenames, wildcards

What would be output if we type something like this in our terminal

```
/home/user/some character with *
```

e.g.

```
/home/renga/i*
```

I pass a variable (`home/renga/i*`) like this in my script, in run time the value was passed along with a file name instead of `/home/renga/i*`.

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question

Comment: see also: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `*` is called a "wildcard" and it's mostly used as a symbol to represent one or more characters.

Consider your example (with added command from me):

```
ls /home/renga/i*
```

where the `/home/renga` directory is like this

```
internal
inspiration
auth
unknown
liar
i*
```

Thus your command will give an output like this:

```
/home/renga/internal
/home/renga/inspiration
/home/renga/i*
```

If you want to access the `i*` directory or file, you need to add a backslash, `\`, in your command, so the command is something like this `ls /home/renga/i\*`, and the output will list the `i*` file or the content of the `i*` directory.

You can also use a quote to avoid matching filenames. So it is would be something like this:

```
ls /home/renga/"i*"
```

You can read more about wildcards [here](http://www.linfo.org/wildcard.html)

Comment: thx all..i just tried escaping the * as well as "*" ,both worked fine and thx for the explanation..